# Module parse failed, Unexpected token (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, installation

just installed ReactJS, but for some reason it displayed error after the 'npm start' command

./src/index.js 1:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:36)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  $RefreshRuntime$ = require('E:/[DON'T TOUCH PLEASE]/myapp/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
  | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);

  ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import './index.css';
   import App from './App';
   import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

   ReactDOM.render(
     <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
     </React.StrictMode>,
   document.getElementById('root')
   );

   reportWebVitals();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the client's package.json file, change the value of react-scripts from 4.0.3 to 4.0.1

save the changes,

run npm install

It will start working...

Comment: thx, but the problem was already solved ))